# Can ActiveAdmin load javascript bundled by webpack? - Rails 5.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I've upgraded from rails 4.2.6 to rails 5.1, and then started to use webpack.
All set up for using webpack have done, but I can't figure out how to load javascript files on the ActiveAdmin page.
ActiveAdmin loads `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee` by default.
Is there a way to load javascript files which is bundled by webpack on the ActiveAdmin page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack is not yet officially supported. The approach we are using for now is to monkey patch ActiveAdmin::Views::Header to include tags to load the generated output of Webpack, eg.

```
class ActiveAdmin::Views::Header < Component
  def build(namespace, menu)
    ...
    render "application/custom_header_tags"
  end
end
```

In our case our custom_header_tags.erb uses [React On Rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial/blob/master/README.md#rails-integration) but substitute whatever integration you prefer.

Comment: Can you detail how you patched that?

Comment: This doesn't work.  Currently fails with "ArgumentError at /admin/trips/1
Can't be in the context of nil."

Comment: [This gist](https://gist.github.com/humphreyja/6de78228186d4e8eaa69ef3b7277c3a1) was published recently defining an ActiveAdmin::Views::React component.

Answer (score 13):

I'm a bit late, but I believe it's better to wrap the method rather than to completely override the class. Also, monkey patching `Header` will result in tags being rendered in div with `id="header"`. In order to render them in `<head />` I did the following:

```
ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base.class_eval do
  alias_method :original_build_active_admin_head, :build_active_admin_head

  def build_active_admin_head(*args, &block)
    original_build_active_admin_head(*args, &block)
    within @head do render '/custom_headers' end
  end
end
```

Put this file to `config/initializers` (so that it won't be reloaded every time in development mode resulting in infinite loop) folder and create a `app/views/_custom_headers.html.erb` file with whatever you need.

Comment: Fails with "ArgumentError at /admin/trips/1
Can't be in the context of nil."

Comment: Just change @header to header and this works.  The error message is rather obtuse.

Comment: Read the above comment as "change `@head` to `head`". I encountered the ArgumentError crash when switching from v1.3.x to v1.4.3, and this change fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

For new apps starting with Rails 6.0, Webpacker has become the default asset generator. You can opt-in to using Webpacker for ActiveAdmin assets as well by updating your configuration to turn on the use_webpacker option, either at installation time or manually.

at active_admin installation:

```
rails g active_admin:install --use_webpacker
```

manually add to config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.use_webpacker = true
end
```

And run the generator to get default Active Admin assets:

```
rails g active_admin:webpacker
```

Comment: now webpacker is deprecated (or "retired" as they call it), so instead of coupling your app to it, better use one of the hacks from the other replies

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for `#build_active_admin_head` continues to evolve. It no longer takes arguments as of ActiveAdmin v1.3.1.

Also, in addition to the method-aliasing and component-overriding methods described in other answers, there is one additional method for monkey-patching ActiveAdmin: `module#prepend`.

Here's how I override the ActiveAdmin body layout (to throw a big "staging" banner across the page in my staging environment) and head layout (to add calls to webpacker's `javascript_pack_tag`):

```
module AdminPageLayoutOverride
  def build_page(*args)
    within @body do
      render "layouts/global/environment_banner"
    end

    super
  end

  def build_active_admin_head
    super

    within @head do
      render "admin/custom_script_tags"
    end
  end
end

ActiveAdmin::Views::Pages::Base.send :prepend, AdminPageLayoutOverride
```