Rails 6 | Active Admin throwing error 'ArgumentError - Can't be in the context of nil'
Rails 6.1.7.10
Ruby 3.2.2
ActiveAdmin 3.0.0
It seems to something related to webpacker, but I'm unable to track the exact solution.
I have been receiving below error while going to any page of my application
ArgumentError - Can't be in the context of nil. [, <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/active_admin-e5ea1803cd68028a35aada6cba9f51369409b50a5199f8201cd991553f64b6f7.css" />    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<script src="/assets/active_admin-1c3ef209e63747c12e4f9a0dc791da6c504724eed86c34d7e662cf166d1cacd5.js"></script><meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="kwzod4T5DHcWN+4sJQpzyFndaX4LpHoPoupmN23uAbjRCRouOoKSkMw5XhLw9Xt+2mXy8ojuhuVGeneCusapAw==" />  </head>
</html>
]:

assets/config/mainfest.js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link active_admin/print.css//= link_tree ../builds

config/initializers/active_admin.rb
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
# config.use_webpacker = true
meta_tags_options = { viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }
config.meta_tags = meta_tags_options
config.meta_tags_for_logged_out_pages = meta_tags_options

Assets files path
assets/javascripts/active_admin.js
assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css


It seems like the error is coming from arbre Does any of this help: https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre/issues/24, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840109/can-activeadmin-load-javascript-bundled-by-webpack-rails-5-1/47055840
